# Linking 1 view controller to two .h files

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In my app, I have a view controller on a storyboard linked to a .h file. I would like though to insert a UITableView, andy link it to a separate view controller .h. But the problem is that in the class for my view controller, i can only select one .h, not two, so I can't link the table view. If I charge it on a second view controller it works, but in this way it doesn't. what can I do??

Comment: emm... cannot understand what do you want to do...

Comment: I have a view controller in storyboard linked to a class (.h, .m), and I have a separate .h,.m for my table view. How can I link the tableview to the correspondent .h if it is in the same view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what do you want to do, you want to give access to table of your tableViewController to another viewController.

UITableViewController has `tableView` property that you can pass to your viewController or to any other class, that needs this tableView. You can pass it, for example, using property in class that needs this tableView. Like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UITableView* tableView
```

after this you will be able to write this code

```
[classInstanceThatNeedTable setTableView:tableView];
```

Comment: [classThatNeedTable setTableView:tableView]; gives an error

Comment: what an error? post code and error message. property declaration must be in .h file of class, that needs this tableView. classInstanceThatNeedTable is instance of this class